# Can't use cordova-plugin-file in Chrome : SecurityError when calling window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL

Tags: javascript, cordova, google-chrome, cordova-plugin-file

I use latest **cordova** with browser platform (I do know it is some quite experimental).

I need to read and write in the **cordova.file.dataDirectory** directory. filePluginIsReady event is correctly fired in Chrome, and I put my read/write action in its callback.

I use **cordova-plugin-file** (latest), working great with Firefox and Internet Explorer 11, but with Google Chrome, calling **window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL** always raise this **FileError** :

**code: 2
message: "It was determined that certain files are unsafe for access within a Web application, or that too many calls are being made on file resources."
name: "SecurityError"**

I carefully read cordova-plugin-file README and the quircks about browser and chrome (large quota is granted, filesystem is initialized).

Adding --allow-file-access option to chrome launcher did not help to access filesystem:file:///persistent/.

With the specific code for Chrome in cordova-plugin-file, I was hoping it would work flawlessly. Any clue ?

Comment: did you try also --allow-file-access-from-files ?

Comment: I'm having a similar problem. Did you ever solve this?