# How to get FileEntry object while using Cordova Simulate

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2017, cordova-plugins, tools-for-apache-cordova

I'm trying to follow the [Take a picture and get a FileEntry Object](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera#module_camera.getPicture) example for the Cordova Camera Plugin. I'm using Cordova Simulate in
Visual Studio 2017 to test the example by selecting "Simulate In Browser"

Taking a picture works and the image is shown in the simulator, using the same `imageUrl` that is passed to the Cordova Files Plugin in this code snippet:

```
function cameraSuccess(imageUri) {
  window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(imageUri, function () {
    console.log('success')
  }, function (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
  });

  return imageUri;
}
```

However, the call to resolveLocalFileSystemURL fails with the following error:

> A URI supplied to the API was malformed, or the resulting Data URL has
>   exceeded the URL length limitations for Data URLs.

What do I need to do to get this working?

**EDIT**
I found this instruction in the [Chrome Quirks](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-file#chrome-quirks) section of the plugin documentation

> resolveLocalFileSystemURL method requires the inbound url to have
>   filesystem prefix. For example, url parameter for
>   resolveLocalFileSystemURL should be in the form
>   filesystem:file:///persistent/somefile.txt as opposed to the form
>   file:///persistent/somefile.txt in Android.

So I changed the code to:

```
  if (device.isVirtual) {
    if (!window.isFilePluginReadyRaised) {
      //added to check another potential Chrome quirk
      //the alert wasn't never shown so I don't think it's an issue
      alert('!window.isFilePluginReadyRaised');
    }

    imageUri= 'filesystem:' + imageUri;
  }

window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(imageUri, function () {
  console.log('success');
}, function (error) {
  console.log(error.message);
});
```

Now the error message is:

> It was determined that certain files are unsafe for access within a Web application, or that too many calls are being made on file
>   resources.

Another Chrome quirk is:

> Chrome requires --allow-file-access-from-files run argument to support
>   API via file:/// protocol.

It is not clear whether Cordova Simulate launches Chrome with this argument. This problem has been raised before:

[Cordova: Launching chrome with --allow-file-access-from-files from VS 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47154220/150342)

[Can't use cordova-plugin-file in Chrome : SecurityError when calling window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34925292/150342)

So perhaps the solution is to get Cordova Simulate to "allow-file-access-from-files" ? How would I test that hypothesis?

**EDIT**
One way to test the hypothesis is to run the simulator from a command line as suggested in a comment under [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48854125/150342). You can get the command to run by typing `chrome://version/` in the address bar after launching the simulator. I added the flags `--allow-file-access-from-files` and `--unlimited-quota-for-files`, but got the same security error

Comment: You might want to create an issue [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/cordova-simulate) as the readme states that the file plugin is supported in cordova-simulate.

Comment: @Phonolog issue raised as you suggested: https://github.com/Microsoft/cordova-simulate/issues/258

Comment: @Colin What exactly you are trying to achieve by using camera plugin in a browser platform?

Comment: @Gandhi Cordova simulator is a web application for simulating cordova plugins. Visual Studio 2017 uses it to simulate mobile devices. The camera plugin works in the simulator. The file plugin does not (or it doesn't when launched from Visual Studio 2017). That means I am only able to develop using a mobile device, which is limiting when I also want to connect to a web service within my development environment

Comment: @Colin But i guess you can make use of the browser platform which does not mandate you to use the device and it also supports both file and camera plugin too

Comment: @Colin Any thoughts on this?

Comment: @Gandhi I'm afraid I don't understand your comment. I'm trying to get a FileEntry object while using Cordova Simulate, and I'm finding that I can't when it's launched from Visual Studio 2017

Comment: @Colin Why dont you use browser platform which lets you test the app in browser instead of cordova serve?